# No sound feedback when changing volume (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, taskbar

I am getting no notification sound when I increase/decrease the volume from the task bar. So, as a result, I am unable to hear how loud the new volume of sound is. I can play music normally and I am getting other sound notifications from the OS. I am using Windows 10.

[image: Taskbar volume control]

For example, when I increase my volume in the above image from 21 to 100, I am not hearing any sound.

Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: I have the same behavior when using the volume up/down multimedia keys. I'd love to configure/hear some sound feedback, so that I know how loud the volume is after my change.

Answer (score 2):

Are you changing volume using the scroll wheel? If so, that doesn't produce any sound on Windows.

If not, check that the default sound is enabled. First type "sound" into your Start menu and pick the first result ("Sound"). On the Sounds tab, select "Default Beep" in the list, and make sure it's not set to None.

Comment: I am not scrolling but clicking. Default beep is not none. Still, the issue is there. Anything else that you can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, your example is the volume of the Speakers, I suggest you turn on the volume synthesizer to modify and try again, Please tell me if it works.

[image]

I hope my answer is helpful to you.

Comment: No, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> and this menu will pop up:

[image: Audio menu - Mix tab]

Then, in the menu, change **System Sounds** to maximum. This worked for me.